# Dart/Docker - VSCode | How to set breakpoints in local code when attaching to docker container's dart process

Tags: docker, dart, docker-compose, vscode-debugger

Recently I have been dabbling with dart servers. I wanted to get everything to be dockerized for debugging purposes and likely eventually for release purposes. I have a server that I am successfully serving in a docker container. I am successfully attaching to the process in vscode by usings the `launch.json` dart/attach method the comes with the dart extension and by setting a `enable-vm-service=<port>` on `dart run` and making sure that port is exposed in my docker-compose. After attaching, I cannot add any breakpoints from my local machine. Interestingly the uncaught exceptions break as expected, showing me where they failed, however the file that opens to show the breakpoint seems to be from the container. Any ideas on how to get the breakpoints to work from my local machine? Direction is enough a solution would be a plus :D Side note. I am on windows.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    env_file: .env

    volumes:
      - ./bin:/app/bin

    ports:
      - "${HOST_API_BINDING:-8080}:8080"
      - "${VM_SERVICE_PORT:-10000}:10000"

    restart: unless-stopped

    tty: true
```

Dockerfile

```
# Use latest stable channel SDK.
FROM dart:stable AS build

# Resolve app dependencies.
WORKDIR /app
COPY pubspec.* ./
RUN dart pub get

# Copy app source code (except anything in .dockerignore) and AOT compile app.
COPY . .
RUN dart pub get --offline

ENTRYPOINT bash
```

server start command:

```
dart run --enable-vm-service=10000 ./bin/server.dart
```

server.dart

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'dart:developer' as dev;
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart';
import 'package:shelf_router/shelf_router.dart';

// Configure routes.
final _router = Router()
  ..get('/', _rootHandler)
  ..get('/echo/<message>', _echoHandler);

Response _rootHandler(Request req) {
  return Response.ok('Hello, World!\n');
}

Response _echoHandler(Request request) {
  var message = request.params['message'];
  return Response.ok('$message\n');
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  // For running in containers, we respect the PORT environment variable.\
  var server = await initServer();

  final info = await dev.Service.getInfo();
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
  final observatoryUri = info.serverUri;

  print(observatoryUri?.path ?? 'Null');
}

Future<HttpServer> initServer() async {
  // Use any available host or container IP (usually `0.0.0.0`).
  final ip = InternetAddress.anyIPv4;
  // Configure a pipeline that logs requests.
  final _handler = Pipeline().addMiddleware(logRequests()).addHandler(_router);
  final server = await serve(_handler, ip, 8080);
  print('Server listening on ports ${server.port}');
  return server;
}
```

launch.json

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Docker: Attach to Dart Proccess",
      "type": "dart",
      "request": "attach",
    },
  ]
}
```